# How to unpack a tuple returned from a function and assign it to the columns of the DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've created a function(acct_num_gen), which returns a tuple like below:

```
0    (2581470369, 1357913579)
1    (6789543210, 5555086420)
```

And I'm trying to assign these values to the columns of a DataFrame as below:

```
new_df["Ac1","Ac2"] = csv_input['Acct'].apply(acct_num_gen)
```

But instead of loading the existing columns, it's creating a new column and loading the tuple..Btw I'm new to pandas, can u pls tell how to do this assignment correctly?

Comment: `new_df.loc[:, "Ac1"] = csv_input['Acct'].apply(lambda x: acct_num_gen(x)[0])`
` new_df.loc[:, "Ac2"] = csv_input['Acct'].apply(lambda x: acct_num_gen(x)[1])`

Comment: @bubble. Thanks! It loaded the DF as expected!

Comment: It loaded perfectly for the first time, but I'm facing an issue now which says: `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
new_df[["Ac1","Ac2"]] = csv_input['Acct'].apply(acct_num_gen).apply(pd.Series)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to assign to your dataframe, create a *new* one and then merge them:

```
ac_df = pd.DataFrame(csv_input['Acct'].apply(acct_num_gen), columns=['Ac1', 'Ac2'])

new_df.merge(ac_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the ac_df is loaded with a tuple in the 1st columns as :(2581470369, 1357913579) NaN and while merging its creating 2 more columns instead of merging values with the existing one.